# plotting multiple xts objects in one window

Tags: r, plot, xts, zoo

I have found some answers to this online but for some reason am interpreting incorrectly because I cannot get it to work. My goal is to simply use the `xts` plotting feature (with the the way it creates the axis, gridlines,etc.) to plot multiple plots:

```
x <- xts(data.frame(a=1:100, b=100:1),seq(from=as.Date("2010-01-01"), by="days", len=100))
> plot(x, screens=1)
Warning messages:
1: In plot.xts(x, screens = 1) :
  only the univariate series will be plotted
2: In plot.window(...) : "screens" is not a graphical parameter
3: In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : "screens" is not a graphical parameter
4: In axis(1, at = xycoords$x, labels = FALSE, col = "#BBBBBB", ...) :
  "screens" is not a graphical parameter
5: In axis(1, at = xycoords$x[ep], labels = names(ep), las = 1, lwd = 1,  :
  "screens" is not a graphical parameter
6: In axis(2, ...) : "screens" is not a graphical parameter
7: In title(screens = 1) : "screens" is not a graphical parameter
```

Another try:

```
> plot(x, plot.type="single")
Warning messages:
1: In plot.xts(x, plot.type = "single") :
   only the univariate series will be plotted
2: In plot.window(...) : "plot.type" is not a graphical parameter
3: In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : "plot.type" is not a graphical parameter
4: In axis(1, at = xycoords$x, labels = FALSE, col = "#BBBBBB", ...) :
  "plot.type" is not a graphical parameter
5: In axis(1, at = xycoords$x[ep], labels = names(ep), las = 1, lwd = 1,  :
  "plot.type" is not a graphical parameter
6: In axis(2, ...) : "plot.type" is not a graphical parameter
7: In title(plot.type = "single") :
  "plot.type" is not a graphical parameter
```

To be clear: I can do this using `lines` but I wonder if there is a way to do this all at once.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could coerce to `zoo` to use `plot.zoo`:

```
plot(as.zoo(x), screens=1)
plot(as.zoo(x), plot.type='single')
```

Or, you could install [xtsExtra](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=118) which has a newer `plot.xts` method

```
#install.packages("xtsExtra", repos='http://r-forge.r-project.org')
library(xtsExtra)
plot(x, screens=1)
```

Comment: On the latest version of `xtsExtra` it warns that `xtsExtra::plot.xts` is deprecated and to use `xts::plot.xts`, but the `xts::plot.xts` still is not able to handle multiple time series, and `xtsExtra::plot.xts` does not actually produce a plot.

Answer (score 2):

I could be wrong but I think plot.xts is no longer part of xtsExtra and has moved to the main xts. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241784/how-to-use-plot-xts-with-block-and-events-lines-with-xtsextra-package). Maybe this note will help people in the future trying to figure out plotting in xts..