# How to use Plot.xts with Block and Events lines with xtsExtra package?

Tags: r, events, block, xts

I am trying to plot time series graph with blocks as others did.
See the link for more detail of the example: http://www.r-bloggers.com/plot-xts-is-wonderful/.

1. Firstly, I installed all newest xts (ver:0.9.874) and xtsExtra (ver: 0.0.876) packages from R-Forge: https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=118.
2. Then I tried to load xtsExtra and it shows as follows:

> library(xtsExtra)

Attaching package: ‘xtsExtra’
The following objects are masked from ‘package:xts’:
    addLegend, addSeries, plot.xts

3. When I look at the "plot.xts" components, I didn't see "blocks" and "events".

> names(formals(plot.xts))
>    [1] "x"              "y"              "..."            "subset"         "FUN"            "panels"
>    [7] "multi.panel"    "col"            "up.col"         "dn.col"         "type"           "lty"
>   [13] "lwd"            "lend"           "main"           "clev"           "cex"            "cex.axis"
>   [19] "mar"            "srt"            "xaxis.las"      "ylim"           "yaxis.same"     "yaxis.left"
>   [25] "yaxis.right"    "grid.ticks.on"  "grid.ticks.lwd" "grid.ticks.lty" "grid.col"       "labels.col"
>   [31] "format.labels"  "shading"        "bg.col"         "grid2"          "legend.loc"

4. Finally when I used plot.xts, it shows the following message.
   Warning message:
   xtsExtra::plot.xts is deprecated, use xts::plot.xts

I really appreciate it if anyone can tell me:

1. If these packages versions are the right ones or not. If not, where are the old versions of xts and xtsExtra that had "blocks" and "events" functions.
2. If these new versions can do the same thing, how?

Please let me know if you need the data to try and I will provide separately since it is big.

Answer (score 0):

We've moved plot.xts into the main xts package.

Please do

```
 install.packages("xts", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

or

```
 install_github('joshuaulrich/xts')
```

and then look at ?plot.xts and ?addEventLines for examples.