# xts plot in a loop: no output

Tags: r, xts

The standard *plot* method immediately displays a result. But with xts objects, this only works when *plot.xts* is not called within a loop. For example, this code works correctly:

```
library(xts)
data(sample_matrix)
sample.xts <- as.xts(sample_matrix)
plot(sample.xts)
```

Whereas the following code does not display any result:

```
# dev.off()
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
for (i in seq(2)) {
    plot(sample.xts)
}
```

Where is the plot in the second case?
And why xts.plot does not act like the standard plot function?

Comment: Check this [out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992831/plotting-multple-xts-objects-in-one-window)

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, @ChirayuChamoli ! Indeed, coercing to `zoo` helps in this case.

Comment: it works as expected, not reproducible

Comment: @sandipan you mean, the second code snippet works correctly? Why is the plot not displayed? I'm using RGui and  Eclipse + StatET plugin.

Comment: @LarsK., yes for me it displays the two plots side be side as expected, using RStudio

Comment: OK, apparently the version I am using (0.10-0, https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts) behaves differently than the official version 0.9-7 from cran. I installed the latter one and it works in all of the mentioned IDEs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Plot returns a plot object, which in your first case gets printed by default. In a loop, or function, you need to explicitly print it.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
for (i in seq(2)) {
    print(plot(sample.xts))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this remark! As I mentioned earlier, I was using version 0.10-0 from github that explicitly needs a print statement. In version 0.9-7, this was not necessary.

Comment: I needed it with xts version 0.9.874, from within RStudio.