# xts plot not showing up in new device/window

Tags: r, plot, time-series, xts

Following data can be either a `tibble` or `data.table`:

```
  datetime                volume
  <dttm>                   <dbl>
  2020-08-25 09:30:00.000      0
  2020-08-25 09:30:12.000    107
  2020-08-25 09:30:50.000    221
  2020-08-25 09:30:50.000    132
  2020-08-25 09:30:50.000    148
  2020-08-25 09:30:50.000    100
  2020-08-25 09:30:50.000    100
  2020-08-25 09:30:58.000    100
  2020-08-25 09:31:56.000    157
  2020-08-25 09:32:36.000    288
  2020-08-25 09:32:36.000    100
  2020-08-25 09:33:10.000    235
  2020-08-25 09:33:23.000    182
  2020-08-25 09:33:44.000    218
  2020-08-25 09:33:44.000    179
  2020-08-25 09:34:18.000    318
  2020-08-25 09:34:27.000    101
  2020-08-25 09:34:27.000    157
  2020-08-25 09:34:27.000    200
  2020-08-25 09:34:27.000    114
```

I have converted above data into a `xts` object and wanted to call the plotting function from `Rscript`, as a command line utility.

Here's how I transform my data into `xts`:

```
data %>% as.xts() -> testdata1
```

Above line of code does not make a different time series than:

```
data %>% as.xts() -> testdata2
identical(testdata1, testdata2)
# output: TRUE
```

on SO there were 2 possible methods to go about this:

```
  # first option
  x11()  # linux calls x11()
  plot(x = data, 
       observation.based = TRUE, 
       major.ticks = "seconds", 
       main = "Test Plot")
  prompt <- "press any key to close the plot"
  capture <- tcltk::tk_messageBox(message = prompt)
  
  # second option
  png("test.png")
  plot(x = data, 
       observation.based = TRUE, 
       major.ticks = "seconds", 
       main = "Test Plot")
  dev.off()
  browseURL("test.png)
```

Neither of above worked for `xts` object plotting. it worked for plain `data.frame`, `data.table` and `ggplot`.

Anyone has tried plotting `xts` to the new device, from command line?

Comment: Both plotting methods worked with the following example: `data(AirPassengers); xts1 <- as.xts(AirPassengers)`. I think your error is with how you convert to `xts` object

Comment: @astrofunkswag not sure that's right; I was `as.xts` as well; and more importantly, `AirPassengers` has different resolution than mine, i.e. mine is irregular time series in seconds, `AirPassengers` was equidistant yearly data; if you could reproduce the plot using my example data that'd surely mean something wrong with my way of plotting. But yes I should add how I transform my data.

Comment: Maybe the resolution is a problem though. I just tried equidistant hourly data; it didn't work for  me either.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue, but referencing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39850348/xts-plot-in-a-loop-no-output) helped solve it for me.

Try assigning the returned plot object and then printing.  e.g.

```
  png("test.png")
  plt <- plot(x = data, 
              observation.based = TRUE, 
              major.ticks = "seconds", 
              main = "Test Plot")
  print(plt)
  dev.off()
  browseURL("test.png)
```